# show running config of samba

Tags: configuration, samba, samba4

Is there a way to unambiguously get the running config of a samba daemon?

I can't find any reference to it in the manual. Of course you run testparm, but  that would only show the validity of the explicit configuration; I would also like to the see the implicit config which is loaded

Comment: Why not just look at `/etc/samba/smb.conf`? That's samba's config file.

Comment: But I also want to see the things that are not explicitly stated in the config file

Comment: `testparm -v` should show the default settings as well.

Comment: Like what? You need to be more specific about what you are looking for.

Comment: my original problem is that I have two instances of samba on different nodes, same config files, same version, yet different behaviour. So I wanted to verify that the configs loaded "in mem", at runtime, are the same. Tbh, I am not sure how I can be more clear than using the term "running config".

the `testparm -v` is enlightening, but still does not ask the running process for its running config. It's like asking for the current running firewall and you want me to look at e.g., `/etc/iptables.save` instead of invoking `iptables -L`

Comment: Another valid reason for such a command would be to verify that on-the-fly edits to `smb.conf` have been hot-reloaded, as Samba should. In fact this is the reason I found my way to this question.